# マージソートを行うプログラムを作ったが、手を加えたはずの配列が何も変わらず帰ってきてしまう。

Tags: c++

マージソートを行うプログラムを作りましたが、手を加えたはずの配列が何も変わらず帰ってきてしまいます。いろいろ調べた結果、mergeで並びを変えたはずの配列がrecMergeSortに戻ってくると変更前に戻ってしまっていました。配列の受けわたしがうまくいっていないのが原因だと思われますが、どこが間違っているのかがわかりません。

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "recFunc.h"

using namespace std;



int main() {

    const int NUM_VALUES = 8;

    int mergeArray[NUM_VALUES] = {6, 3, 5, 1, 8, 2, 4, 8};

    // show starting array
    cout << "Starting array is " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
        cout << mergeArray[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // now sort it
    mergeSort(mergeArray, NUM_VALUES);

    // show updated array, should be in ascending order
    cout << "Now the array should be sorted" << endl;
    cout << " expected: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" << endl;
    cout << " actually: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
        cout << mergeArray[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl << "Done with testing merge sort" << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**recFunc.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "recFunc.h"

void mergeSort(int* array, int size)
{
    recMergeSort(array, size);
}

void recMergeSort(int* array, int size)
{
    if(size <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int middle = (size - 1) / 2;
    int* arrayLeft = new int [middle+1];
    int* arrayRight = new int [(size-1)-middle];
    for(int i = 0; i < middle+1; i++)
    {
        arrayLeft[i] = array[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < (size-1)-middle; i++)
    {
        arrayRight[i] = array[(middle+1)+i];
    }

    recMergeSort(arrayLeft, middle+1);

    recMergeSort(arrayRight, (size-1)-middle);

    int* temp = merge(arrayLeft, middle+1, arrayRight, (size-1)-middle);

    array = temp;

}

int* merge(int* arrayLeft, int leftSize, int* arrayRight, int rightSize)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int leftEnd = leftSize-1;
    int rightEnd = rightSize -1;

    int* temp = new int [leftSize+rightSize];

    while(left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd)
    {
        //if left value is smaller, save the value to temp
        if(arrayLeft[left] <= arrayRight[right])
        {
            temp[left+right] = arrayLeft[left];
            left++;
        }
            //otherwise(right value is smaller), save it
        else
        {
            temp[left+right] = arrayRight[right];
            right++;
        }
    }

    while(left <= leftEnd)
    {
        temp[left+right] = arrayLeft[left];
        left++;
    }
    while(right <= rightEnd)
    {
        temp[left+right] = arrayRight[right];
        right++;
    }



    return temp;
}
```

**recFunc.h**

```
int* merge(int* arrayLeft, int leftSize, int* arrayRight, int rightSize);
void recMergeSort(int* array, int size);
void mergeSort(int* array, int size);
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
void recMergeSort(int* array, int size)
{
    ...
    array = temp;
```

引数 `array` を変更しても、`array` が指す配列は変更されません。`temp` の内容を1要素ずつ `array` が指す先にコピーするか、`merge()` 関数に書き込み先として `array` を渡すとよさそうです。

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = temp[i];
    }`　　のようにやってみてうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。しかし、いまだになぜ‘array=temp‘がダメなのわかっていません。もう一度説明していただいてもよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: C言語の原則で、仮引数の値を変更しても呼び出し側には何も影響を与えないです。この場合は `array` が仮引数ですね。
呼び出し側に影響を与えるためには、引数をポインタにして(これはできてました)、ポインタが指す先を書き換える必要があります。